# Set number of threads when auto compiling kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, multi-threading, compilation

I use Ubuntu as main operating system.

I have found that when a new kernel is included in a system upgrade, during the upgrade, certain kernel-related items are compiled (kernel modules?).

During this process, I check that the processor usage is low, as it is making use of 1 single processor thread.

With multicore technologies available today, is there any way to set that, every time there is a kernel update, all the cores of the system can be used in such compilations? Or at least be able to decide the number of cores desired for the compilation.

Thanks.

Comment: [Perhaps this Q&A at AskUbuntu answers this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534661/how-to-parallelize-dpkg-for-large-dkms-packages)

Comment: Yes, I will try! Thanks

Comment: Nop... it doesn't work. I apply this yesterday. Today there was a kernel update and my system just used 1 thread to compile the modules :(

Comment: Was the environment variable correctly set? Remember that `sudo` by default clears environment variables, so you'd have to use `sudo CONCURRENCY_LEVEL='16' apt upgrade`

Comment: I wrote `export CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=8` in `/etc/profile` so it was defined in the environment variables at startup

Comment: `sudo` will reset it afaik.

Comment: What will be reset?

Comment: By default `sudo` resets all environment variables to mitigate some security concerns.